# difference between pip install -r pip-requires VS setup.py install

Tags: python, pip

If I have a python project called "A", it has dependency on libraries B,C,D,E,F. So in my pip-requires file I have something like:

```
B>=1.0
C
D
E<=0.7.2
F
```

in this case, I found that running `setup.py install` and `pip install -r pip-requires` a bit confusing. My understanding is that `setup.py install` installs the project itself without dependencies, `pip install -r pip-requires` installs all the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install -r pip-requires` will only install the dependencies as mentioned in the `pip-requires` file. `setup.py install`, will install the project itself *along* with the dependencies as mentioned in `install_requires` within `setup.py`